# EditText widget auto-size

Tags: android

Is a there a method in XML by which I can autoset the size of a widget (as 'EditText') automatically?

I'm asking this because, setting fixed values for width and height, I'm afraid not to respect the screen size of any device in which my app will live.

For example:

I need to set a width that will take a margin of 15dp from left edge, regardless from the device (so the screen size) used.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have to define your values on _dimens.xml_ for diffrent screen sizes.
You might find a better idea from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: Use `android:match_parent` or `android:wrap_content` as appropriate for the width and height of your View. `Can anyone help me?` Yes, the android developers site. Just google for `android supporting multiple screens`

Answer (score 0):

You may Use `android:match_parent` or `android:wrap_content` as appropriate for the width and height of your View. it handle the width and height according to the device. for example see below code

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>
```